# Adding data to a QTreeWidget by Drag and Drop

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtreewidget

I am trying to drag and drop a folder into a a QTreeWidget and it will print out all the files in that folder and any other folder structures under that. I am very unfamiliar with QTreeWidget and in my example I was just trying to add data under the 'Name' column everything I tried i got different errors from `model is a private method` to `argument 1 has unexpected type 'Tree'`. How can I add data under each column?

```
import os
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileSystemModel, QApplication, QAbstractItemView, \
    QMainWindow, QPushButton, QTreeWidget, QTreeWidgetItem
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


class Tree(QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.resize(600, 600)
        self.setHeaderLabels(['Name', 'Size', 'Upload Status'])

        model = QFileSystemModel()
        model.setRootPath(QDir.currentPath())
        model.setReadOnly(False)

        self.setSelectionMode(self.SingleSelection)
        self.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)
        self.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setDropIndicatorShown(True)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            event.setDropAction(Qt.CopyAction)
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            event.setDropAction(Qt.CopyAction)
            event.accept()
            for url in event.mimeData().urls():
                if url.isLocalFile():
                    rootPath = url.toString()[8:]
                    if os.path.isfile(rootPath):
                        address = rootPath
                        item = QTreeWidgetItem()
                        item.setData(self, 0, 0, address)
                        self.addItem(item)
                    else:
                        for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(rootPath):
                            for file in files:
                                address = str(url.toLocalFile())
                                path = path.replace("\\", "/")
                                directory_name = path.replace(rootPath, "")
                                displayName = directory_name + '/' + file
                                address += displayName
                                item = QTreeWidgetItem()
                                item.setData(self, 0, 0, address)
                                self.addItem(item)

        else:
            event.ignore()


class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Login Form')
        self.resize(1200, 600)

        self.treeBox = Tree(self)
        self.btn = QPushButton('Upload', self)
        self.btn.setGeometry(850, 400, 200, 50)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Main()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

For example if I drop a folder that contains file1, file2, subfolder, and subfolder2 the treewidget will display the root folder with each file as a child. Along with the subfolders in the root will also display their children(files inside the subfolder).

Comment: Your question is not clear, better explain what you want, perhaps a practical example of what you want to obtain

Comment: Also consider that QTreeWidget has its own internal, private model (hence the error you are facing). Just like the other "high level" views, QListWidget and QTableWidget, they are only used as *convenience classes* that provide simpler implementations. If you need to set a specific model, you need to use their ancestor: in your case, a QTreeView.